# I need cypress not to delete cookies and cache

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress, e2e-testing

I'm automating an application where when accessing a functionality (through a previous login) cypress, perhaps, understands that it is a new redirect and deletes cookies and cache and drops the login session, making it impossible for me to access the functionality.

The code is still very basic, just content with clicks and form filling to get to the functionality I need:

```
describe('go to the function', () => {
  const username =  'username'
  const password = 'password'

  it('just visit', () => {
    cy.visit('/')
  })

  it('insert the infos', () => {
      cy.get('.kt-form > :nth-child(1) > .form-control')
      .type(username)

      cy.get('.kt-form > :nth-child(2) > .form-control')
      .type(password)

      cy.get('.kt-login__actions > .btn').click()
  });

  it('go to admin page', () => {
    Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
      return false;
    })
      cy.get('.kt-header__topbar-user')
      .click()

      cy.get('.kt-nav__link-text')
      .should('be.visible')
      .click()

      
  })

  it('Go to function that I need', () =>{
    cy.get('.swal2-confirm')
    .should('be.visible')
    .click()

    cy.get('.kt-menu__nav > :nth-child(3) > .kt-menu__link')
    .click()
    
  })

  it('does nothing because I cant go on LOL', () =>{
    
  })
     
})
```

Comment: Which version of Cypress are you using?

Comment: the version is 10-9-0